# Correct way of pushing the code from a branch to the master branch in git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

I have a doubt regarding the steps which we follow to push the code in a branch.

So in our application, we have a master branch and I have created a branch of the master branch for my own practice where I make changes for a given case. When it is reviewed by my manager, I need to push that code on the master branch.

Below are the steps I follow for pushing the code: 
Master branch name - development
My local branch name - neil/development

1. Initially I go to **development** branch and do **git pull** so that I have the latest version of the master branch.
2. After that I go to my branch using **git checkout neil/development** and merge it with the Master branch **development** so that my own branch and master branch are inline using **git merge development** command
3. After that I merge the master branch with my own branch **neil/development** so that my changes are merged with the master branch.

After this, I commit all the changes and push them.

I have read about **rebase and cherry pick** commits but I don't know how to use it.

Could you guys guide me if I can push my own branch changes to the master branch in a simpler manner?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make the history look the way your boss wants and push that.

Answer (score 0):

I rebase my commits into master with the following steps.

`git co development`

`git pull`

`git co your-branch-name`

`git rebase development` (you can also use interactive rebase which allows you to reword, pick and choose commits)

`git co development`

`git rebase your-branch-name` (you can also use `git merge your-branch-name`)

`git push`

Before pushing into master, I would advise you to do a `git log`, `git status` and a `git diff master` (development) to make sure you do not push in any unnecessary commit.